# How to build a correct XML request using android-ksoap2?

Tags: java, android, xml, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am trying to call a webservice from Android project, but I am not able to pass any parameter.

I need to build a request like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="www.mywebservice.com">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:MyMethodName>
      <ns1:appUser>0</ns1:appUser>
    </ns1:MyMethodName>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But using ksoap2, I get it like this:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <v:Header />
  <v:Body>
    <MyMethodName xmlns="www.mywebservice.com">
      <appUser>0</appUser>
    </MyMethodName>
  </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

My code is:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
request.addProperty("appUser",0);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
envelope.implicitTypes = true;

envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
httpTransport.debug = true;

httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

Tried many examples, but nothing seems to work - I am not able to buil the correct XML request.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem:

1. Created a new class which extends *SoapSerializationEnvelope* and Override its method *write* - which I have modified to fit my needs:

   ```
   public class MyNewClass extends SoapSerializationEnvelope {

           public MyNewClass (int version) {
               super(version);
           }

           @Override
           public void write(XmlSerializer writer) throws IOException {
               env = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
               String tem = "www.mywebservice.com";
               writer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
               writer.setPrefix("SOAP-ENV", env);
               writer.setPrefix("ns1", tem);
               writer.startTag(env, "Envelope");
               writer.startTag(env, "Body");
               writer.startTag(tem, "MyMethodName");
               writeBody(writer);
               writer.endTag(tem, "MyMethodName");
               writer.endTag(env, "Body");
               writer.endTag(env, "Envelope");
               writer.endDocument();
           }
       }
   ```
2. Instead of using *SoapSerializationEnvelope*:

   ```
   SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
   ```

I use my new created class:

```
MyNewClass envelope = new MyNewClass (SoapEnvelope.VER11);
```